# File Curruption whenever trying to download a video using the following code

Tags: python, python-3.x, download

This function takes a URL , destination and file name and well downloads the file. But when i tried it for a video using the Google Photos API, the video file gets this error :

`OSError: MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file .\ImageBin\yolo.mp4.`

Here is the code for the downloading part:

```
def download_file(url: str, destination_folder: str, file_name: str):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(os.path.join(destination_folder, file_name), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
```

EDIT: All the errors I get while running :

```
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Garg\PycharmProjects\Google Meets Intagram\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 286, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    match = re.findall("([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9])", line)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/defaultuser100000/Google Meets Intagram/Downloading_random_image_from_Google_Photos.py", line 122, in <module>
    upload_video_to_instagram(r'.\ImageBin\yolo.mp4', cap)
  File "C:\Users\defaultuser100000\Google Meets Intagram\Uploading_Photo_to_Instagram.py", line 14, in upload_video_to_instagram
    bot.upload_video(video, caption=caption)
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Garg\PycharmProjects\Google Meets Intagram\venv\lib\site-packages\instabot\bot\bot.py", line 822, in upload_video
    return upload_video(self, video, caption, thumbnail, options)
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Garg\PycharmProjects\Google Meets Intagram\venv\lib\site-packages\instabot\bot\bot_video.py", line 20, in upload_video
    video, caption=caption, thumbnail=thumbnail, options=options
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Garg\PycharmProjects\Google Meets Intagram\venv\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api.py", line 865, in upload_video
    return upload_video(self, video, caption, upload_id, thumbnail, options)
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Garg\PycharmProjects\Google Meets Intagram\venv\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api_video.py", line 110, in upload_video
    video, thumbnail, width, height, duration = resize_video(video, thumbnail)
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Garg\PycharmProjects\Google Meets Intagram\venv\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api_video.py", line 248, in resize_video
    vid = mp.VideoFileClip(fname)
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Garg\PycharmProjects\Google Meets Intagram\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 91, in __init__
    fps_source=fps_source)
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Garg\PycharmProjects\Google Meets Intagram\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 36, in __init__
    fps_source)
  File "C:\Users\Aryan Garg\PycharmProjects\Google Meets Intagram\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 291, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    filename, infos))
OSError: MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file .\ImageBin\yolo.mp4.
Here are the file infos returned by ffmpeg:

ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122

  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt

  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100

  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100

  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100

  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100

  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100

  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100

  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100

  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100

Input #0, jpeg_pipe, from '.\ImageBin\yolo.mp4':

  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A

    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 262x512 [SAR 1:1 DAR 131:256], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc

At least one output file must be specified
```

Invoking Function:

```
holy_image = choice(Base_URL_list)
```

Despite its name holy_image is really just a list of URLs can be both video and Images

Comment: Are you using the MoviePy package? The error seems unrelated to this function. Also, please include the code/line that is calling the function.

Comment: @sam No I am not using the MoviePy Package. There were a bunch of errors mostly unrelated to the video, if you want i could edit the post and show all the errors

Comment: The full error stack trace would be great, yes, along with how you're invoking the function. Please edit them in the post. Anyhow, MoviePy is definitely being used, either by you somewhere else in the file or by some other package that you're using. Are you using any third-party packages?

Comment: Just edited the post, and yes I am using Third-Party Packages, (instabot) to upload to Instagram, it has the following function: `bot.upload_video(video, caption=caption)`

Comment: The file is not corrupted.  Not all mp4 files have a duration in their header.

Comment: @TimRoberts should I import the metadata with the file? Would that help?

EDIT: IT WORKS!!! thanks Tim!. You can put it in the answer if you want